# Regex match all php tags pairs

Tags: php, regex

How to match all php tags pairs and contents between them.
I using this regexp: `/<\?.*\?>(?=[^'])/mgs` and my text is

```
<? $b = '?>';$c = '';$d = '';$e = '';$a = 1;?><div><? $a = 1; ?>`
```

My regex gives me only first match `<? $b = '?>';$c = '';$d = '';$e = '';$a = 1;?>`

Actual php code:

```
$matches = [];
$str = '<? $b = \'?>\';
$c = \'\';$d = \'\';$e = \'\';
$a = 1;?><div><?  ?>';

preg_match_all('/<\?.*\?>(?=[^\'])/sm', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: The regex you have given is not a valid PHP (PCRE) regex since there is no `g` pattern modifier.  Please show your actual PHP code.

Comment: @salathe the g modifier is present `/mgs`, it also isn't required to be present

Comment: I think what you're looking for is this `<\?.*?\?>(?=[^']|$)`

Comment: @ctwheels yes it works, thank you

Comment: @ctwheels: `(?=[^'])` doesn't prove anything, you can't know if a quote is a closing quote or an opening quote. As an aside `(?=[^']|$)` can be shorten with a negative lookahead:`(?!')`

Comment: @ctwheels and its presence makes it an invalid regex in PHP, as I said. It is *required* to *not* be present.

Comment: After some tests, it seems unfortunately that the tokenizer doesn't support the old opening tag `<?`. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

My first idea was to use the tokenizer, but after some tests, it seems that this one isn't able to recognize the short open php tag `<?`.

I decide to write a pattern that describes the two pitfalls: comments and strings.

```
$str = <<<'EOD'
<? $b = '?>';
$c = '';$d = '';$e = '';
$a = 1;?><div><?  ?>';
EOD;

$pattern = <<<'EOD'
~
# subpatterns definitions
(?(DEFINE)
    (?<sqs> # single quote string
        ' [^'\\]*+ (?s: \\. [^'\\]* )*+ '
    )

    (?<dqs> # double quote string
        " [^"\\]*+ (?s: \\. [^"\\]* )*+ "
    )

    (?<identifier> [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]* )

    (?<hds> # heredoc string
        <<< (?| \g<identifier> | " ( \g<identifier> ) " ) \R
        (?: .* \R )*?
        \g{-1} ;? \R
    )

    (?<nds> # nowdoc string
        <<< '( \g<identifier> )' \R
        (?: .* \R )*?
        \g{-1} ;? \R
    )

    (?<str> \g<sqs> | \g<dqs> | \g<hds> | \g<nds> )

    (?<slc> // .* ) # singleline comment

    (?<mlc> /\* [^*]*+ (?: \* (?!/) [^*]* )*+ (?:\*/)? ) # multiline comment

    (?<comment> \g<slc> | \g<mlc> )
)

# main pattern
<\? (?:php)? \s
(?<content>
     [^</"'?]*+ 
    (?:
        \g<comment> [^</"'?]*
      |
        \g<str> [^</"'?]*
      |
        < [^</"'?]*
      |
        \? (?!>) [^</"'?]*
    )*+
)
(?: \?> )?
~x
EOD;

if ( preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $matches) )
    print_r($matches['content']);
```